# From mathematic function to c++ code

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement this F(S) function:

[image]

bellow is my code but is not working:

```
double EnergyFunction::evaluate(vector<short> field) {
    double e = 0.0;
    for (int k = 1; k < field.size() - 1; k++){
        double c = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i < field.size() - k; i++) {
            c += field[i] * field[i + k];
        }
        e += pow(c, 2);
    }
    double f = pow(field.size(), 2) / ( 2 * e );
    return f;
}
```

For example F(S) function should return value 8644 for vector:

```
1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1
```

I need another par of eyes to look at my code because I am a bit lost here. :)

Comment: Yes sorry, i was trying that and I forget to change it back, when posting on stackoverflow

Comment: It seems, you do not map the range [1, L] to the range [0, size-1] properly.

Comment: Yes L is size, in our case that is 305.

Comment: You have several issues with switching from 1-based to 0-based indexing. For example, `field[i] * field[i + k]` can multiply the same element by itself in your code, but not in the formula.

Comment: Is this the minimal data set that reproduces the problem? You never use the 0th element, is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after refactoring:

```
double EnergyFunction::evaluate(vector<short> field) {
  double e = 0.0;
  int l = field.size()
  for (int k = 1; k < l; k++){
    double c = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0, j = k; j < l; i++, j++) {
        c += field[i] * field[j];
    }
    e += c*c;
  }
  return l*l / ( e+e );
}
```

explanation:
1. we need to iterate (L-1) times
2. we need to shift the base and offset indexes until we reach the last one
3. c*c and e+e are quicker and easier to read

Comment: Getting refactoring right is hard, as you are finding out :-). I'd recommend doing the refactoring in the math itself first, then do a direct copy into code.

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping variables into different ranges using the same names, which is always going to be confusing. Better is to keep ranges and names the same as in the math, and only subtract one for 0-base indexes at indexing time. Also might as well use L explicitly:

```
int L = field.size();
for (int k = 1; k <= L-1; k++){
    ...
    for (int i = 1; i <= L-k; i++) {
        c += field[i -1] * field[i+k -1];
    ...
```